# Can all followers quest be done in one playthrough?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

As I understand, several (if not all) of the companion quests require certain "trigger points" to initiate their quests. If I complete say Arcade's quest, can I then return to Veronica and run HER quest or has "the train left the station" so to speak?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* do all the companion quests in a single playthrough.  I've done this myself.  Nothing inherent in one companion's quest line will force you to be unable to complete another.

There are numerous ways to lock yourself out of being able to do individual companion's quests - allying with the Legion, for instance, is likely to make some of them challenging if not impossible.  There are also dialog choices that must be picked carefully.  Finally, on Hardcore, it's possible for your companions to die permanently as well.

Thus, I'd suggest carefully proceeding with each companion's quest so as to avoid these scenarios.  The order in which you complete them doesn't matter, though.